# gae local environment is not running for wordpress latest version, works only with 3.5.1

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, google-app-engine

Google app-engine for wordpress is not running with the latest version in the local environment . I have configured every thing as per their tutorial at [gae_help_page](https://developers.google.com/appengine/articles/wordpress)

They say it works for only Wordpress-3.5.1 and I have tested it with 3.5.1 it was running but when I use Wordpress-3.8.2 , keeping other thing same , it shows:

```
Error Establishing Database Connection
```

Thank in advance, I want to use the latest version of Wordpress.

Answer (score 0):

This is known to work fine with the current version of WP (3.9), at least on OS X.
I suspect you have a mysql-related configuration issue.  First, make sure that your mysql server is running on your local machine and that you have created the db that you want to use for the local installation.

Then, your `wp-config.php` should include something like this (edited appropriately for your setup)-- check that the local config values are correct:

```
if (isset($_SERVER['SERVER_SOFTWARE']) && strpos($_SERVER['SERVER_SOFTWARE'],'Google App Engine') !== false) {
    /** Live environment Cloud SQL login and SITE_URL info */
    define('DB_HOST', ':/cloudsql/your-project-id:wordpress');
    define('DB_USER', 'root');
    define('DB_PASSWORD', '');
    define('DB_NAME', 'your-wordpress_db');

} else {
    /** Local environment MySQL login info */
    define('DB_HOST', '127.0.0.1');
    define('DB_USER', 'your-local-user');
    define('DB_PASSWORD', 'your-local-password');
    define('DB_NAME', 'your-local-wordpress_db');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

```
/** Local environment MySQL login info **/
define('DB_HOST', '127.0.0.1:8889');
//define('DB_HOST', '127.0.0.1');
    define('DB_USER', 'root');
define('DB_PASSWORD', 'root');
define('DB_NAME', 'wordpress');
```

I'm using MAMP, if your are using a different installation probably the DB port changes.

I Hope it helps!